# Method Invocation 'setGravity' may produce java.lang.nullpointerexception-ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I am using `ProgressDialog` in one of my android application. its showing me warning as above title. I have used it in java like below. This is not duplicate question. I have searched for solution but have not found it.

```
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog((this),R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    mProgress.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    mProgress.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
```

anyone can please suggest me this can cause error or it will not ? how can I solve it ?

Comment: Hey ! its not same question...please check it

Comment: You can check for null before setting gravity though like if(progressDialog.getWindow()!=null){mProgress.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);}

Comment: this means that `getWindow()` may return null, if the dialog is not attached to a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assert the warning by,

```
    Window window = mProgress.getWindow();
    assert window != null;
    window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
```

or you can wrap it with a if case by

```
    Window window = mProgress.getWindow();
    if ( window != null )       
       window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
       window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
```

And its just a lint warning, you can ignore that.

Comment: Thanks.... it have solved :)

Comment: @MeenaSingh Please also consider the comment from Vlad Matvienko. There is possibilty of the window will be null.